# Warning log for sprintf function in widget.php

Tags: wordpress, printf

every time my wordpress theme load my host add 50 line in error_log file like this:

```
[22-Sep-2017 13:00:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments in ..../wp-includes/widgets.php on line 672
```

Wordpress v4.8.2

Comment: Please refer to this link `https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-sprintf-too-few-arguments-4/`

Comment: @AnandChoudhary Thanks but i got "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Comment: sorry use this link [(https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-sprintf-too-few-arguments-4/)]  @saman use this link

Comment: @AnandChoudhary . this log not on behalf of my theme or plugin. this is about wordpress file(widget.php). specifically this line `$params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_widget'], $id, $classname_);`

Comment: Plese check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sprint arguments should be like this

```
<?php
$number = 9;
$str = "Beijing";
$txt = sprintf("There are %u million bicycles in %s.",$number,$str);
echo $txt;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I use %d more than 10 time in some custom widget and that cause log.